# Cmake's generated makefile getting a rule not found

Tags: makefile, cmake

For some reason CMake generates a buggy makefile:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `CMakeFiles//Users/wen/projects/Space Cubes/src/Debug.cpp.dir/depend'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Users/wen/projects/Space Cubes/src/Debug.cpp.dir/all] Error 2
```

What's happening here and why can't it work? I have tried clearing caches already.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(spacecubes)

if (APPLE)
    FIND_LIBRARY(OPENGL_LIBRARY OpenGL)
    FIND_LIBRARY(GLUT_LIBRARY GLUT)
    SET(EXTRA_LIBS ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY})
else (APPLE)
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT} gl glu glut)
endif(APPLE)

file(GLOB_RECURSE src "src/*.cpp")
add_executable(${PROJECT} ${src})
```

Comment: Can you show the CMakeLists file?

Comment: Oh sorry, forgot about that.

Comment: I don't have access to an Apple, so I'm only going to point to a few issues: 1) You don't check if the `find_library` calls succeed (i.e. checking the values of `${OPENGL_LIBRARY}` and `${GLUT_LIBRARY}`). 2) You don't use these even if they *are* found - I'd expect to see `${EXTRA_LIBS}` used in a `target_link_libraries` call somewhere. 3) the existing `target_link_libraries` needs to be moved to *after* the `add_executable` command or it will fail. 4) `file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)` isn't recommended for gathering lists of sources since it needs cmake to be explicitly rerun if a new file is added.

Answer (score 2):

It was posted years ago and I wanna say I am suffering the same issue when I try to use add_executable and add_library at the same time.... I am looking for the solution as well.

cmake version: 2.8.7
system: Ubuntu 12.04

Update:

Hi, I am back here to answer the question.

The problem happens because the executable and lib have the same target name, in your case, it's ${project}, so cmake generates some bug code in the makefile.

In addition for Apple system, Apply use the case-insensitive file system by default, so if you use same name with different upper or lower case, it will end with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

This should fail when you generate the project.

${PROJECT} should be empty. I don't see where you are defining it.

add a line set(PROJECT "spacecubes") and it should build fine.